# How to fix dark screen after locking iphone 4 ios6?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen

The last week or two my iphone 4 started dimming it's screen to almost black whenever I lock it. Then when I unlock it I have to get to the brightness slider and move the slider to restore light to the screen.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: But when you lock the phone, the screen shuts off completely. So when does the screen start dimming?

Comment: @bassplayer7 Good point. So it must be either when I lock the screen or when I wake it back up via the power or home button I guess. So annoying.

Comment: I think I've run into that problem (bug) a few times before. If you haven't already, reboot your phone, and turn off "Automatic Brightness".

Comment: Great! Glad it fixed it. I'll go ahead and turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had that issue before, and it indeed seems to be a bug of sorts. As evidenced by the fact that one shouldn't have to hold their phone up to direct light, or manually adjust brightness on a frequent basis.

I would recommend starting with a phone reboot - hold down the power *and* home button *until* you see the Apple logo. This may help the situation

Next, you could also try turning off "Automatic Brightness". Open the Settings app, tap "Brightness & Wallpaper", then switch "Auto-Brightness" off.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for auto-brightness was adjusted significantly in iOS 6.

Rather than before where you would see an immediate change on turning on auto-adjust, now it's a more gradual process, and you can actually see the slider moving as it makes updates.

Also, another change is that the auto-adjust now works on the lock screen, so at night you won't be blinded, and in the day you can actually see the screen in day light.

Personally, I found it very annoying for about 2 weeks, and now I've adjusted to it, I find it works much better than before. If I want to manually control the screen, pointing it at a bright light causes it to brighten significantly, etc.

Finally, some sites have suggested that you can "tune" or reset it by turning auto-adjust off, setting the brightness to minimum, then turning auto back on.

Worth noting, that as I'd had to get my flashlight replaced right when iOS 6 came out, I actually assumed it had broken the ambient light sensor and I took the phone to the apple store because the auto-adjust switch didn't work as it had previously. The geniuses had no explanation for the new behaviour. I had to google it myself, and plenty of other people have complained about it.

Comment: Informative but not an answer